# Install Ubuntu 16.04.1 amd64 on a Lenovo T61

Tags: system-installation, live-cd

Can I install Ubuntu 16.04.1 desktop amd64 on a laptop with Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU T7100 @ 1.80 GHz and 2 Gb of RAM? I already have Windows 7 and it runs on 32 bit.
I want to install Ubuntu along Windows 7 and using pictures, videos and books with both systems. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can, I have exactly the same laptop (T61) and am running Kubuntu amd64 on it without any issues. All the special thinkpad keys (volume, brightness etc..) work fine too. 
 However 2GB of ram (same for me) is not much, which means you'd better not open too many applications at the same time. I would advise  a decent swap partition too (I've setup mine at 3GB).

Comment: Ubuntu and Kubuntu aren't same. Ubuntu uses lot more RAm

Comment: Thank you, I have searched more and found the i386 version, which is probably the one I want to use **along Windows 7**. My other question was: "Is it possible?"

Comment: @Anwar-Shah Where can I find the answer(s) for the **exact duplicate** question you marked about mine? Please? The answers in this very stream are not to my question.

Comment: @DanMP There could be practically infinite number of combinations of hardware specs and for each of them supporting a question is not possible. The target link has necessary information about Ubuntu's requirement. After knowing that, You should determine yourself. Another reason is, the answers would be opinion-based, which are not suitable for SE sites

Comment: @DanMP check this too http://askubuntu.com/q/206407/176889

Answer (score 0):

2 GB isn't much, **but it's enough** for Ubuntu :) *Windows 7 use more RAM memory than Ubuntu* :) I'm now using my older PC with 2 GB RAM (1,8 because 128 MB is VRAM), and it's enough :)